# Call a function from an account

Tags: truffle, javascript, testrpc

Knowing that
account0 = 0x2ac971cfceb478a3db5a43598e098839007cec34
account1 = 0x55990a8c443a0eb296cff4bece4c54350185b019

I started testrpc. After that, I called a function `buyItem(moneyPaid,{from:account1})` in a javascript test file. Then I verified the `msg.sender` inside the function. I realized that the `msg.sender` is not `account1`. Plus, it changes every time I called the function. Can anyone explain why the `msg.sender` is not account1 nor any account on the `web3.eth.accounts` list?

Answer (score -2):

It happens. I faced it when my web3 object was not getting injected properly. I was using metamask then. 
Everytime I was trying to use the msg.sender, it was giving me some other address than the account selected in metamask.

You please check in the browser console, by putting some flags, whether your web3 is getting injected properly or not.

It's going to be the case, most probably.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. You are suggesting _what_ to do but not _how_.